Is referring to default values in another file allowed in hydra config?
Is this allowed in hydra config? I have seen this file before but I don't know if this behavior is allowed as I can't find that in the documentation
defaults:
  - ../../../../common/conf/model/mixtral-8x7b@_here_

name: mixtral-8x7b

torch_dtype: float16

padding_side: "left"


By default, Config groups are relative to the config group of the config refering to them.
Hydra does officially support accessing config group in an absolute manner by prefixing with /.
The way this is done here is not supported and might work accidentally but could in theory cause some issues.
The example above can likely be replaced with the documented:
defaults:
  - /common/conf/model/mixtral-8x7b@_here_

Absolute config group entries are documented in The Defaults List page.
The _here_ keyword is documented in the Packages page.
